# transfer pricing a cost when posting collateral

Tags: margin, collateral

I am trying to understand how transfer pricing is accounted for for margined trades.

The treasury department within a bank will provide trading desks funding at some base rate plus a transfer pricing spread: the cost of funding.

For an uncollateralised derivative, future payments should be discounted at this funding cost.

For a margined derivative, future payments are discounted at the collateral rate, which is usually the base rate. However, a trading desk will need to fund any margin calls, and presumably this funding is obtained from treasury at a rate of `base + transfer-pricing`.

Let's assume that the future value of a derivative contract is `-$100`, with a present value of `-$95` discounted at the base rate. At t=0, the holder must post `$95` to the contract counterparty.

Given the desk will be funding at base + tp, does this mean that the desk's net cash position at termination of the contract will be `-($100 + transfer-pricing-cost)`? This seems like a logical conclusion, however it is contrary my company's (a financial institution) internal company material indicating that margined trades cost/earn the base rate, in which case I am puzzled as to 'where the transfer pricing goes'.